# Use url_for of Flask in ajax function

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm using Flask to create a little WebApp. In the file.py there is a

```
render_template('index.html', listaimmagini = listaimmagini)
```

where "listaimmagini" is a list of images name (According to Flask standard, the images are in static folder). Now in "index.html" i'm trying to show these images but seems that webapp doesn't found it in static folder (there is the usual broken icon for all my images)

Where is the error in my code?

Index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){

var img = [];
{% for imagelego in listaimmagini %}
img.push("{{url_for('static', filename = imagelego)}}");
{% endfor %}


    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll')[0];
    if(img.length>0){
        parent.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
        for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
            image = document.createElement('IMG');
            image.src = img[i][0];
            image.alt = '';
            image.setAttribute("class", "scegli");
            parent.appendChild(image);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: For one of these images, what is the *correct* path (where are they located in your `static` folder) and what is generated instead (view the source of the generated page and look at the URL there, or right-click the broken image icon and get the URL from that).

Comment: If i have the "{{url_for('static', filename = imagelego)}}" outside ajaxscript i see in the right way my image (with right-click on image i see the url http://127.0.0.1:4555/static/ivl.png)... but in the code that i posted (url_for... inside ajaxscript) i don't see the image and with right-click on broken image icon i see the url 'http://127.0.0.1:4555'

Do you understand what happened?

Comment: obvisiouly 'ivl.png' is one element of listaimmagini list...

Comment: So what exactly is being generated? View the source of your page, and paste the generated HTML here.